# How to place triangle “^” on the top of content box with css?

Tags: html, css

```css
#redbox{
width:100%;
height:152px;
background-color: #d12c3d;
}


.arrow_box {
 position: relative;
 background: #88b7d5;
 border: 4px solid #c2e1f5;
  height: 100px;
  width: 10%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
 bottom: 100%;
 left: 50%;
 border: solid transparent;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
 border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
 border-bottom-color: #88b7d5;
 border-width: 50px;
 margin-left: -50px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
 border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
 border-bottom-color: #c2e1f5;
 border-width: 56px;
 margin-left: -56px;
}
```

```html
<div class="jumbotron-fluid" id="redbox">
  <div class="arrow_box">
  </div>
  <div class="arrow_box">
  </div>
  <div class="arrow_box">
  </div>
  <div class="arrow_box">
  </div>
</div>
```

Hi I want to place a triangle on top of a div. The div should contain the content and and up triangle has the icon.

Inside this div I want to place the other div's with triangle, and I need it to be responsive as well.

I need the output like this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/h75Vl.png

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? You need to at least show us what you've tried so far.

Comment: yeah..I tried but i cant post the code I had a "error" .It show your post mostly code so try to explain

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/paolobasso99/ccerdcbn/1/).

```
.box {
    position: relative;
    border: 2px solid #000;
  margin-top:35px;
}
.box:after, .box:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.box:after {
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    border-width: 30px;
    margin-left: -30px;
}
.box:before {
    border-bottom-color: #000;
    border-width: 36px;
    margin-left: -36px;
}
```

```css
.box {
 position: relative;
 border: 2px solid #000;
  margin-top:35px;
}
.box:after, .box:before {
 bottom: 100%;
 left: 50%;
 border: solid transparent;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.box:after {
 border-bottom-color: #000;
 border-width: 30px;
 margin-left: -30px;
}
.box:before {
 border-bottom-color: #000;
 border-width: 36px;
 margin-left: -36px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
my content
</div>
```

Comment: thank you..But how can i add the icon on the triangle.please check the image ineed like that https://i.stack.imgur.com/h75Vl.png